# How do I make a better algorithm, so something doesn't 'stack overflow' all the time?

Tags: c#, stack, overflow, stack-overflow

First off I am writing a little bubble clicker game, in which you click a bubble (in Dutch 'Bubbel') and all bubbles of that same color that are directly touching a popping bubble will pop.

I have a little problem with a piece of code, and I don't know why it keeps doing this.
Here's the code:

```
public void checkIfNeighbors(int x, int y)
    {
        bool left = false;
        bool right = false;
        bool up = false;
        bool down = false;
            if(x != 0)
                left = Bubbels1[x - 1, y].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x - 1, y].IsAlive;
            if(x != 11)
                right = Bubbels1[x + 1, y].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x + 1, y].IsAlive;
            if(y != 0)
                up = Bubbels1[x, y - 1].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x, y - 1].IsAlive;
            if(y != 11)
                down = Bubbels1[x, y + 1].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x, y + 1].IsAlive;
            if (left)
            {
                pop = true;
                checkIfNeighbors(x - 1, y);
            }
            if (right)
            {
                pop = true;
                checkIfNeighbors(x + 1, y);
            }
            if (up)
            {
                pop = true;
                checkIfNeighbors(x, y - 1);
            }
            if (down)
            {
                pop = true;
                checkIfNeighbors(x, y + 1);
            }
            if (pop)
            {
                Bubbels1[x, y].IsAlive = false;
            }
    }
```

Is there a way to make this faster and more efficiënt?
Also it produces a stack overflow all the time, but when I reduce the 'ifs' to just one 'if' it doesn't (even if my bubble line is 12 of the same bubbles long)

I don't know what I have done, but it has worked before somehow...

Comment: Everytime i think of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEi4I6UWuDQ)

Comment: Consider using version control so you can see what you changed. Do you know what a stack overflow is?

Comment: Looks like an infinite recursion. For example, checkIfNeighbors calls the function for the left neighbor. The left calls the same function for the right neighbor, which is the bubble you just had. And that one calls the function again for the left one, and it bounces back like that forever. Just add a check to IsAlive to prevent that. And just go into debugger mode and follow the program step-by-step, you'll see what's happening.

Comment: The wording `produces a stack overflow all the time` indicates to me a lack of conceptual understanding of what a stack overflow is, or also that you're failing to see that what you're you're getting is actually an exception. Please be more specific about *exactly* what you did to make it work.

Comment: Tell it to break on a stack overflow exception and just let it run. Look at the call stack when it happens

Comment: Bubble, not bubbel. Sorry, it was driving me crazy.

Comment: I know what a stack overflow is, Bubbles1 is a multidimensional array, I think Pierre-Luc has got the right answer, The reason some things in this post are strangely written (Eg. Produces a stack overflow all the time, and bubbel (Dutch for bubble)) is because I am dutch, and thus it is harder for me to phrase some technical terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what happens when you have 2 alive bubbles at 5,4 and at 5,5.  Let's say you call `checkIfNeighbors(5,4)`.

It will see the neighbor to its right and [recurse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) by calling `checkIfNeighbors(5,5)`.

That call will notice that its neighbor to the left needs to be processed (another call to `checkIfNeighbors(5,4)`.

This becomes a never ending cycle, and you'll soon see a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) error.

The fix is to pop the current bubble **before** processing any of the neighbors.

**---edit---**

We need to handle the "I have no neighbors" condition in two ways:

if called from the main program, we don't pop the bubble.

If called as a result of recursion (i.e., this is the last bubble to pop), we pop the bubble.

The fix is to pass a flag:

```
public void checkIfNeighbors(int x, int y, bool inRecursion)
    {
        bool left = false;
        bool right = false;
        bool up = false;
        bool down = false;
            if(x != 0)
                left = Bubbels1[x - 1, y].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x - 1, y].IsAlive;
            if(x != 11)
                right = Bubbels1[x + 1, y].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x + 1, y].IsAlive;
            if(y != 0)
                up = Bubbels1[x, y - 1].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x, y - 1].IsAlive;
            if(y != 11)
                down = Bubbels1[x, y + 1].GetType == Bubbels1[x, y].GetType && Bubbels1[x, y + 1].IsAlive;
            if (left)
            {
                Bubbels1[x, y].IsAlive = false;
                checkIfNeighbors(x - 1, y, true);
            }
            if (right)
            {
                Bubbels1[x, y].IsAlive = false;
                checkIfNeighbors(x + 1, y, true);
            }
            if (up)
            {
                Bubbels1[x, y].IsAlive = false;
                checkIfNeighbors(x, y - 1, true);
            }
            if (down)
            {
                Bubbels1[x, y].IsAlive = false;
                checkIfNeighbors(x, y + 1, true);
            }
            if (inRecursion)
            {
                Bubbels1[x, y].IsAlive = false;
            }
    }
```

In your initial call, set inRecursion to **false**: `checkIfNeighbors(5,7,false)`.

Comment: But now `pop` will always be false before checking for the neighbors and will not execute.

Comment: Where has `pop` gone?

Comment: `pop` is no longer necessary - just set `Bubbels1[x,y.IsAlive = false` directly

Comment: This is what I did before, and yes this worked, however, how about the last bubble? This bubble is still a bubble of the same type but has no neighbors...
It won't be popped this way.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the original intent.  If `checkIfNeighbors(x,y)` should *always* pop the bubble at x,y then all you'd need do is move `Bubbels1[x, y].IsAlive = false;` to the top of the function.

Comment: I forgot to post a rule, but if it's only one bubble it shouldn't pop, only if it's pairs of 2 or more.